# I have a TURN server, but what do I lack ?

Tags: ios, webrtc, easyrtc, apprtcdemo

I am building a WebRTC videoconferencing service for iOS and Web.  We have so far used  [tokBox](https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/client/), they deliver the whole package (client API (ios and web) + TURN server. Their solution also takes care of generating tokens and session ID etc.  But we want to have our own setup, and a partner has given us a TURN server.  But, what do we miss to be able to have a webRTC video conference between iOS and a web client?  What service will let us just plug in the TURN server address/credentials and have it work both from a web and iOS client?  Are these suitable packages: EasyRTC, SkyLink, AppRTC ? We don't need a lot of features, just 1-1 videocall with no bugs. Which one is best?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at minima you will need a signaling server.
apprtc is a complete application, it is not suitable for what you have.
tokbox is a PaaS, so you could replace it with another PaaS (skylink, forge, ...)
easyrtc gives you the code of a signaling server, but not the infrastructure (load balancing, ...), you can use it if you re ok to host it.

you might want to go for peerJS (open source, both hosted and DIY options) if you really want to do it yourself. Otherwise, just changing PaaS is not making a lot of sense. You have to think about everything you're gonna lose as well (recording, archiving, media server, ...).

If your use case is well defined, you can ping me offline, and i'll point you to additional resources.

Answer (score 0):

You can look to Kurento media server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the service provided by [anyconnect SDK](http://anyconnect.com/webrtc/). They provide the leading Peer to Peer connectivity between any two nodes whether browser, desktop or mobile platforms. They also provide STUN,TURN and Signaling (SIP,XMPP) server support. Using their SDK will let you just plug in your server credentials and transfer any type of data.